# ActionBar with fragments accessing widgets from fragments crashes the app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an activity (TabActivity.java) that contains a fragment container in it's layout, which is populated with fragments on click in actionbar.
Now, in the menu of the action bar I have a menu-option (a button) that does the saving of the contents from the fragments.

My problem is as follows:
I have a fragment fragment_aloc.xml where I have a textview and an EditText with id = "edaloc"
I want on click of the save button (menu) to get the value from this editText
I want to do the same for all fragments (get values from widgets that are located in the fragments) in order to save the values in a database.

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.save:
            ... // here I place the code that gets the values from the fragments
            }
}
```

But when I try to do that (click on the save button) I receive an error:

> 4805-4805/ro.myapp.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException at ro.myapp.app.TabActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(TabActivity.java:134)

And the line (134) to which it points says:

```
EditText edalocare = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edaloc);
```

I tried to do it like bellow too:

```
EditText edalocare = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.edaloc);
```

Same error.
The thing is that I see the fragment, and I see the edittext. But I can't seem to be able to access it

What is the problem and how can I avoid/solve it?

I repeat: my goal is to have **multiple fragments**, with EditTexts and RadioGroups on them. An d on click in the menu, I want to **get all values** inserted in them and **save them in a database**.

Thank you
**EDIT**

So I am trying right now this code:
In my fragment (java code) is now:

```
public class aloc_fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aloc, container, false);
    }
    public String getEditValue(Integer id){
        EditText edu = (EditText)getView().findViewById(id);
        return"";
    }
}
```

And inside my Activity, I try to access the value of the "edaloc" EditText like this:

```
Fragment fragment1 = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("aloc");
String val_aloc = fragment1.getEditValue(R.id.edaloc);
```

But it does not work.(The Tag of the fragment is declared inside the Layout of the fragment) The "fragment1.getEditValue(R.id.edaloc);" is not recognized...

What am I still doing wrong?

**EDIT**
The code of the activity is (minus the code for the actionBar Tabs):

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity {

Fragment fragmentTab1 = new aloc_fragment();
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If from your activity you try to access a widget that is defined in your fragment (is in the fragment's layout), you cannot do this by calling `findViewById()` from the activity. You need to call this method from your fragment. What you can do is:

1. Define a public method on the fragment class/classes. This method should return the value from your `EditText`. You can safely use `findViewById()` in this method as you're accessing your `EditText` within the fragment where it's defined.
2. As you create your fragments manually, you can give each fragment a tag as you create it. Store the tags of the created fragments in your activity.
3. When you need to obtain the values from the fragments, use `findFragmentByTag(String tag)` method for each tag you stored. Then call the method you added in point 1 and get the value from `EditText` this way.

Comment: Please check out my EDITS in the question

Comment: How do you create/add your fragments?

Comment: Check the EDITED question above

Comment: I need to know how to you add your fragments in your activity? Do you use `FragmentManager`?

Comment: I use a TabListener (because the whole activity is actionBar based. So I switch the fragments inside a TabListener class.Like bellow `public class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
Fragment fragment;
public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
  this.fragment = fragment;
}
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){
 ft.remove(fragment);
}
}`

Comment: And no, I don't use FragmentManager

Comment: Should I use GlobalVariables class? And set the variable in onDetach of each fragment? Would that be a good approach? Why is it so hard to get info from a fragment?

Comment: I followed this example for building the activity with actionBar and fragments. Please look at it: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture08/lecture08.html And tell me how to access an editText from a fragment, while in a menuItem selected

Comment: FragmentTransaction has an overloaded replace method where you can specify a tag. You can later use this tag to get tour fragment using findFragmentByTag.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51519/discussion-between-user1137313-and-szymon)

Comment: I can't now, I have to go in a few minutes. Later ok.

Comment: Please when you return take a look at the link I gave above (dartmouth) as a base for my code, and use that in a new answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. I just wanted to ask you if it would be a good idea to :

- Inside the fragment class: get the values and put them inside 
  globalVariables
- In the Activity: get the values from the GlobalVariables and use them

Is this a good approach?

So far I only found (apparently) a problem. I can do it with GlobalVars, but I can only populate the globalVariables on events of the fragment, such as OnCreate, onAttach, OnDetach, onPause and so on.
And that means that if the user is inside a fragment, and accesses the save button in the actionBar, then the visible fragment will not have set the globalVariables. So if on the visible fragment there is an EditText, and I enter some text there... on Save button will do "the saving" using the globalVars, but the editText value will not be populated with the value from the currently opened fragment because there is no event fired that contains the setter of the value in the globalVars.

So my answer to my question is that it's not a good approach, because the visible fragment with the values on it will not be saved.

I even tried to replace the current fragment with another (empty/save) fragment in the container before starting to do the saving... and oddly enough it seems that onDetach does not get fired fast enough?!?!?

Comment: Solved this problem too, by setting the global var from a textWatcher listener, that I set up on each fragment class. So problem solved. Maybe not the most elegant solution but at least it works